# Utilization data for DynmoDB AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to pull the utilization data for dynamoBD.

```
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace = 'AWS/DynamoDB',
        Period = period,
        StartTime = start_time ,
        EndTime = end_time,
        MetricName = 'ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits',
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Dimensions = [
            {
                'Name': 'DEVINT_Job_Status',
                
                'Value': ''
            }   
        ])
```

**what should i put under value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the dimension name should be `TableName` and the value should be the name of the table that you are interested in.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html

So, for example:

````
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace = 'AWS/DynamoDB',
        Period = period,
        StartTime = start_time ,
        EndTime = end_time,
        MetricName = 'ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits',
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Dimensions = [
            {
                'Name': 'TableName',
                'Value': 'DEVINT_Job_Status'
            }   
        ]) ```
````

Comment: Bro i am getting null values. Do we need enable cloudwatch metrics manually pull utilisation data?